# Is there a way to download a file using browser from RESTful webservice which asks for Authorization header

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, restful-authentication

I am currently trying to download the file using ajax request from my REST based servie using browser as.

```
$('#button').click(function (url)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + token);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        alert('success')
        //what should I do here to get file downloaded using browser
    };
    xhr.send();
}););
```

Comment: you can use my https://github.com/rndme/download project to download a Blob, which you can get from _e.response_  in _onload()_ if you set `xhr.responseType="blob";` after you _open()_.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code.

```
$('#button').click(function (url)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + token);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        alert('success')
        var file=e.target.files[0]; //you can get file this way.
    };
    xhr.send();
}););
```